# How do I find the schema of a table in an ODBC connection by name?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rodbc, r-dbi

I'm using the `odbc` package to connect to a MS SQL Server

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver   = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                 Server   = "server",
                 Database = "database",
                 UID      = "user",
                 PWD      = "pass",
                 Port     = 1111)
```

This server has many tables, so I'm using `dbListTables(con)` to search for the ones containing a certain substring. But once I find them I need to discover which schema they are in to be able to query them. I'm currently doing this manually (looking for the name of the table in each schema), but is there any way I can get the schema of all tables that match a string?

Answer (score 2):

Consider running an SQL query with `LIKE` search using the built-in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` metadata table if your user has sufficient privileges.

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE '%some string%'
```

Call above with R `odbc` with a parameterized query on the wildcard search:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
strSQL <- paste("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME" ,                
                "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA",
                "WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE ?SEARCH")

# SAFELY INTERPOLATED QUERY
query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, strSQL, SEARCH = '%some string%')

# DATA FRAME BUILD FROM RESULTSET
schema_names_df <- dbGetQuery(conn, query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around using the RODBC package:

```
library('RODBC')
# First connect to the DB
dbconn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver = {ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server};
                            server = server;
                            database = database;
                            uid = username;
                            pwd = password")
# Now fetch the DB tables
sqlTables(dbconn)
```

For my specific DB I get:

```
names(sqlTables(dbconn)
[1] "TABLE_CAT"   "TABLE_SCHEM" "TABLE_NAME"  "TABLE_TYPE"  "REMARKS"
```

Comment: great stuff; what are the requirements for this to work? 
(reading elsewhere that some linked list tables are proprietary and not indexed, wondering if THIS would even work here... or if it depends on indexing / some_schema_criteria / specific SQL type (looking at connecting using ODBC) thanks